# Ruby 1.9.3 hash syntax not working with rspec-rails 2.9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 project I just started, and I'm trying to write some tests.

When I try to utilize Ruby 1.9.3's JSON-esque hash syntax and do this:

```
let(:user) { User.new(first_name: 'Joe', last_name: 'Blow') }
```

or this:

```
let(:user) { User.new({first_name: 'Joe', last_name: 'Blow'}) }
```

I get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
  let(:user) { User.new(first_name: 'Joe', last_name: 'Blow') }
                                   ^
```

When I revert to the :key => 'value' syntax, rspec then looks at the user.rb file I'm requiring and says it doesn't know what is going on with the syntax present there, either.

Is there a way I can remedy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest version of Rspec-Rails. That should do it.

Comment: @rpearce Out of curiosity, what version did you have installed before?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall To be honest, I am unsure. It couldn't be very old, and gem list / gem list -l gave me no love.